# How to delete certain pattern in a record?

Tags: perl, shell, awk, sed

I have a file which has hundreds of recorded in the below format:

```
20150416110321|21,VPLA,91974737XXX5|91974737XXX5,404192086271201|404192086271201,SAI-IMEISV,gsn65.xxxxx.com,gsn65.xxxxx.com;1429148977;301814701;11276100,100.XX.199.250|100.XX.199.XXX|,1,SAIOLU-Location,SAIOLU-LG,2,internet|internet,,SAIOLU-SGSNIP,6,AL,AL_F_1_25G40K_2_25G20K_28|KL_BASIC,,UNKNOWN,SAIOLU-MK,UNKNOWN,SAIOLU-MBRUL,SAIOLU-MBRDL,,,,SAI-IMEI,,,,
```

I want to take only the first part of the pipe separated data in fields/columns 1-8. How can I do that with awk/sed ?

For example:

```
20150416110321,VPLA,91974737XXX5,404192086271201,SAI-IMEISV,gsn65.xxxxx.com;1429148977;301814701;11276100,100.XX.199.250,1,SAIOLU-Location,SAIOLU-LG,2,internet|internet,,SAIOLU-SGSNIP,6,AL,AL_F_1_25G40K_2_25G20K_28|KL_BASIC,,UNKNOWN,SAIOLU-MK,UNKNOWN,SAIOLU-MBRUL,SAIOLU-MBRDL,,,,SAI-IMEI,,,,
```

Thanks

Comment: @Ed Morton : Hi, Please read the question carefully, I wrote I have a file with hundreds of records in below format. Secondly, this is the requirement that the 1st part of the pipe should be taken in the output. I hope I answered your query , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk.

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS="," '{for(i=1;i<=8;i++)sub(/\|.*/,"",$i)}1' file
20150416110321,VPLA,91974737XXX5,404192086271201,SAI-IMEISV,gsn65.xxxxx.com,gsn65.xxxxx.com;1429148977;301814701;11276100,100.XX.199.250,1,SAIOLU-Location,SAIOLU-LG,2,internet|internet,,SAIOLU-SGSNIP,6,AL,AL_F_1_25G40K_2_25G20K_28|KL_BASIC,,UNKNOWN,SAIOLU-MK,UNKNOWN,SAIOLU-MBRUL,SAIOLU-MBRDL,,,,SAI-IMEI,,,,
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . It worked for me. I just had one more query : Is there any equivalent for " sed -i " in awk. I mean I want to write these changes in this file only without redirecting it ..

Comment: it's better to use awk since you want to do the replacement on limited fields ie, upto 8.

Comment: Yes I want to use awk only but want to write the changes again in the same file. So I was asking is there anything "-i" option type like we have in sed. Anyways, thanks for the above solution, it worked as per the requirement. !!!

Comment: @Vieypul The newest version of gawk includes a -i option that works the same way as seds.

Comment: @JID it's actually `-i inplace` in gawk. The `-i` argument tells gawk to include a library, just like using `@include` in a gawk script. The `inplace` option to `-i` is what's telling gawk that the library to include is the one for inplace editing. The fact that sed and awk both have a `-i` arg is completely co-incidental and a little unfortunate since they mean completely different things.

Comment: @EdMorton Ahh right,thanks! I can't use it anyway because I only have 3.2 :(

Comment: @JID then you are missing a LOT of very useful functionality, e.g. `FPAT`, multi-D arrays, sorted `in`, `BEGIN/ENDFILE`, and indirect function calls (calling functions through variables). See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History for the list. I would highly recommend getting the most recent 4.* if at all possible (4.1 is generally available and 4.2 is in beta).

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ':cycle
s/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{0,7\}[^,|]*\)|[^,]*/\1/;t cycle' YourFile
```

recursively remove all content between `|` and next `,` included for first 8 group separate by `,`

Comment: Hi @NeronLe Thanks for sharing the command. This is exactly what I was looking for. A sed command which can edit the file itself. But I am facing one problem here. When I am running the command normally , it is working perfect from the command line but when I am running this in script, it is not showing any error nor any output.  #!/usr/bin/perl

my $cmd2 =`sed -i ':cycle s/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{0,13\}[^,|]*\)|[^,]*/\1/\;t cycle' vpl `;
system($cmd2);

Comment: certainly a shell interpretation, you need to escape some part. Try with a `set -vx;` in form of the sed in the command for debuging. Also you can put the sed action in a file and call it via `sed -i -f YourSedAction.file vpl`. Now, calling from perl, there is certainly a better way directly in perl itself

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I achieve this in perl script ? I thought I need to use sed in perl sccript ?

Comment: sorry for this but perl is not in my expertise :-(

Comment: @Ed Morton Hi Morton, yes I am looking exactly what you wrote as the existing script is written in perl and I just need to modify it as I explained in the question && yes, its a mistake from my side that I didn't tag "perl" in it. Apologies for that ! Thanks